# wordpress - php - Get name and slug from category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I've got this function:

```
<?php
$categories = []; //array to store all of your category slugs
$category_list_items = get_terms( 'product_cat' );

foreach($category_list_items as $category_list_item){
    if(! empty($category_list_item->slug) ){
        array_push($categories, $category_list_item->slug);
    }
}

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'product_cat' => $category, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
?>
```

This is good, it returns the slug of a category for me in a loop. The problem is, now I can't get the category name anymore. I've tried adding another array: '$names = [];' and with that copied the if statement in which I replaced slug with name. But that didn't take. Out all of the solutions that i've tried, I only get returned 'Array' of just the whole list of names. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$categories = array();
$names = array(); 
$category_list_items = get_terms( 'product_cat' );

foreach($category_list_items as $category_list_item){
    if(! empty($category_list_item->slug) ){
        $categories[] = $category_list_item->slug;
        $names[] = $category_list_item->name;
    }
}

foreach ($categories as $key=>$category) {
     echo "Category Name :".$names[$key];
     echo "Category Slug :".$category;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'product_cat' => $category, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
?>
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried this. But how then, do I echo it later on?

Comment: Where do you want to echo the category names ?

Comment: I need to echo them as a title in a <h2> tag

Comment: Are you want to echo the category name in foreach ($categories as $category) { } this loop ?

Comment: yeah, it's after that foreach

Comment: Please check my answer. I have make some modifications.

Comment: The name works now, only the slug doesn't. It just outputs letters: i, b, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58470/discussion-between-suman-biswas-and-luc).

Comment: Sorry. That was my mistake.